# Unable to run java commands using processbuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to run a java class file from another java program.

This is my program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
public class RunJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","HelloWorld");
        pb.directory(new File("/home/local/prasanth-8508"));
        pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.start();
    }
}
```

After running this program I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java"

But when I run any java commands from my terminal, they work absolutely fine.

Another thing I found is, when I run the command: `echo $PATH` in my terminal and using the ProcessBuilder (`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash","-c","echo $PATH");`), they are showing different outputs. i.e The path to **jdk/bin** is not displayed in the ProcessBuilder command.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does `/home/local/prasanth-8508` definitely exist, and do you have permission to access it?

Comment: Yes Micheal, that directory exists. Otherwise I would've got a file no such file error. And I have the permission to access it too.

Comment: That's incorrect - you would have got exactly the error you specified if the directory didn't exist in this case (and depending on your platform, a possible qualifier after that exception to state that the directory was invalid too.) Checking that `java` is on your path would be my next port of call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, As @MichaelBerry said it is possible that you may not have permission to access it but other then that also I want to include,

Here you have started with very good [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) you just need to modify small things like parameter `-jar` in the constructor of processBuilder.

I've posted below sample code which may help you to understand how it will work.

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/java", "-jar", "your.jar");
pb.directory(new File("preferred/working/directory"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: I don't run any jar files. I want to run a class file. And yes, by specifying the absolute path to java, it works. But do you have any idea why it is not working if I give only 'java' instead of the absolute/path/to/java?

Comment: It may possible that you need to set up the environment variable _PATH_ for java bin directory and _CLASSPATH_ for java lib directory in your system without that you need to specify the absolute path of java.